Checking whether the user is a member of the channel
I use python-telegram-bot and I use the get_chat_member method. My code is:
user_id = update.effective_chat.id
print(user_id)
channel_username = "@Numbew"
await context.bot.get_chat_member(channel_username, user_id)

I'm both a member of the channel and an admin of the channel, but it still gives the following error:
File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telegram\request_baserequest.py", line 379, in _request_wrapper
raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: User not found
where is the problem from?
Is there no other method for this? Artificial intelligence does not help either

you are probably confusing
update.effective_user.id with update.effective_chat.id
use these

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples

